# Using `position()` to extract specific element

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have a datafile in a format similar to

```
<!-- mydata.xml -->
<alldata>
    <data id="first">
        <coord><x>0</x><y>5</y></coord>
        <coord><x>1</x><y>4</y></coord>
        <coord><x>2</x><y>3</y></coord>
    </data>
    <data id="second">
        <coord><x>0</x><y>2</y></coord>
        <coord><x>1</x><y>1</y></coord>
        <coord><x>2</x><y>0</y></coord>
    </data>
</alldata>
```

As the `x` values are the same in all my datasets in the xml-files, I would like to extract the data to a csv-format like

```
x;first y;second y
0;5;2
1;4;1
2;3;0
```

Naively, I've tried to match `<coord>` in the first `<data>` element and use `position()` to extract the correct `<y>` from the next `<coord>`'s in the `<data>` element with the second `id` attribute:

```
xml sel -T -t -m "/alldata/data[@id='first']/coord" -v "concat(x,';',y,';',../../data[@id='second']/coord[position()]/y,';',position())" -n mydata.xml
```

This outputs the `<y>` from the first `<coord>` in all lines in the output even though the `position()` is incremented in each line:

```
0;5;2;1
1;4;2;2
2;3;2;3
```

How can I achieve what I set out to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position()` gives the [context's position](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-context-position) (where it's called from). `../../data[@id='second']/coord[position()]` actually means "every `coord` under the second `data` which is **in it's own position**" (which is all of them but XPath 1.0 string conversion only takes the first one).

To refer to the `coord` you're looping on, you can use the XSLT function [current()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current). This doesn't work with `position()` for some good reason that I can't think of right now, but you can [count()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count) the `preceding-sibling` nodes instead:

```
xml sel -T -t -m "/alldata/data[@id='first']/coord" -v "concat(x,';',y,';',../../data[@id='second']/coord[count(current()/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/y)" -n mydata.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for and coulden't figure out myself.